# Is it possible to make a workable copy of recovery media?

Tags: usb-storage

I recently created a recovery flash drive using the HP recovery manager. Since flash drives cannot be trusted for long term, I want to move the contents of my recovery media to the cloud. I want to know if it is possible to use those contents like my recovery media or not? If not then please tell me some other way so that I could be sure that my recovery data is safe.

Comment: Create an Image of the drive using backup software like Acronis or Macrium. Then you can restore the image to a flash drive at any time.

Comment: @Moab Does it matter where I store that image? Have you tried this one, because I  asked HP. They said a recovery media can't be duplicated.

Comment: No it does not matter, in fact store it several places on different storage devices, I have done this for years with HP recovery media with no issues, unless they have done something lately to prevent this but I doubt it.

Comment: @Moab So essentially you mean I should clone my recovery media like I would any other system partition to create the image. Is that what you say or do I need to select any other option specifically for with respect to recovery media? Asking this to be sure.

Comment: Correct, create an image of the usb drive.